# DDoS attack on /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

Was tempted to post this on ServerFault.

Cloudflare enabled with SSL. Got 250k requests in past 2 hours, 192k were cached, the others weren't.

The page that's causing the issue for me is "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php".

The CPU is spiking like crazy here. Been manually adding IP's into server's firewall, but it's not good enough since the IP's keep changing. So site is down because it keeps getting crashed/timeout.

On a dedicated server, anything else I can do besides cloudflare? Have cpanel installed and can add extensions.

Thanks.

Comment: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170196-I-am-under-DDoS-attack-what-do-I-do- https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004256008-How-do-I-use-Rate-Limiting-to-protect-against-DDoS-attacks-

Comment: I'd go for fail2ban, it works like your 'manual job' now but makes it automatically.

Comment: @smith Implemented the things based in those articles, still not much use sadly. Checking fail2ban right now.

Comment: if it was any of my personal sites i would take it off line for a day. let the attackers move on.

Comment: Post on ServerFault, SO is for coding problems.

Comment: @smith There are many kinds of attacker out there, some will move on, some won't, some will return shortly in some days, some weeks... or 5 minutes after your server boot.

Comment: Do these DDOS request have any identifiers in common e.g. same User Agent/query string? If so, 403ing by your web server ("firewall" httpd.conf htaccess) will massively reduce server load and may keep your site up. If this blocking is available via Cloudflare even better. If only a couple of you require WP admin (dashboard) access, then in your particular WP setup it may be practical to password protect WP-Admin dir to restrict admin-ajax (however unrestricted admin-ajax is needed for many WP sites/plugins/themes to function).

Comment: Ended up installing fail2ban, and blocked certain incoming requests, and setup rate limiting on cloudflare. It took care of the issue, but have the ugly 5 second wait screen. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the admin-ajax.php file is supposed to be publicly available, but who puts a file like that in an admin directory? *sigh*.

In addition to using fail2ban (which is a great suggestion) you could try one or more of the following... in no particular order.

1. Look at the user agents used in the attack, if there is a commonality use Cloudflare's User-Agent Blocking.
2. Use use Cloudflare's javascript challenge on the firewall to require visitors from the attacking countries to complete a javascript captcha before being allowed through.
3. Block access to the file (temporarily?) using .htaccess
4. Use a Cloudflare page rule to redirect traffic to that URI to another (e.g. to www.yoursite.com).
5. Use Cloudflare Access to protect your entire /wp-admin directory.
6. Use Cloudflare's zone lockdown to restrict access to that URI to specific IP addresses.